# Determinants of inflation expectation

Tags: reference-request, inflation, expectations

What are the most important factors that determine inflation expectation in a country, both based on theoretical models and on empirical evidence?

If an answer is too lengthy for the site, reference to relevant reading material would also help, or maybe reference to any good survey of literature on this topic.